# Add ebd. if there are several quotation from the same author

Tags: biblatex

I am using Biblatex and Historische Zeitschrift style. Its a great style and I am happy with it but there is one small change I would like to make and its connected with citing different books from the same author. If I cite 3 books from the same author this is what I get in the footnote:

> 1. Cf. William Welsington, An Introduction to LaTeX. Bd. 47. (Latex Guides.) Berlin/New York 1997, P. 82.
> 2. Cf. William Welsington, An Introduction to Bibtexf. Bd. 48. (Latex Guides.) Berlin/New York 1998, P. 5.
> 3. Cf. William Welsington, An Introduction to Biblatex. Bd. 449. (Latex Guides.) Berlin/New York 1999, P. 13.

I would like to get this instead:

> 1. Cf. William Welsington, An Introduction to LaTeX. Bd. 47. (Latex Guides.) Berlin/New York 1997, P. 82.
> 2. Cf. ebd., An Introduction to Bibtexf. Bd. 48. (Latex Guides.) Berlin/New York 1998, P. 5.
> 3. Cf. ebd., An Introduction to Biblatex. Bd. 449. (Latex Guides.) Berlin/New York 1999, P. 13.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@book{welsington1997,
    Address = {Berlin/New York},
    Author = {William Welsington},
    Title = {An Introduction to LaTeX},
    Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    Series = {Latex Guides},
    Shortauthor = {Wel.},
    Shorttitle = {Intr.},
    Volume = {47},
    Year = {1997}}
@book{welsington1998,
    Address = {Berlin/New York},
    Author = {William Welsington},
    Title = {An Introduction to Bibtexf},
    Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    Series = {Latex Guides},
    Shortauthor = {Wel.},
    Shorttitle = {Intr.},
    Volume = {48},
    Year = {1998}}
@book{welsington1999,
    Address = {Berlin/New York},
    Author = {William Welsington},
    Title = {An Introduction to Biblatex},
    Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    Series = {Latex Guides},
    Shortauthor = {Wel.},
    Shorttitle = {Intr.},
    Volume = {449},
    Year = {1999}}
\end{filecontents} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname} 
\begin{document}
\blindtext\footcite[Cf.][P. 82]{welsington1997}
\blindtext\footcite[Cf.][P. 5]{welsington1998}
\blindtext\footcite[Cf.][P. 13]{welsington1999}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following redefinition might do what you want

```
\renewbibmacro*{footcite:full}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibhypertarget{\thefield{entrykey}:\the\value{instcount}}{%
      \usedriver
        {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}%
         \ifciteidem
           {\renewbibmacro*{author}{\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}%
            \renewbibmacro*{editor}{\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}}
           {}%
        }
        {\thefield{entrytype}}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}
```

You will have to enable `idemtracker=true` in the loading-time options.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@book{welsington1997,
    Address = {Berlin/New York},
    Author = {William Welsington},
    Title = {An Introduction to LaTeX},
    Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    Series = {Latex Guides},
    Shortauthor = {Wel.},
    Shorttitle = {Intr.},
    Volume = {47},
    Year = {1997}}
@book{welsington1998,
    Address = {Berlin/New York},
    Author = {William Welsington},
    Title = {An Introduction to Bibtexf},
    Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    Series = {Latex Guides},
    Shortauthor = {Wel.},
    Shorttitle = {Intr.},
    Volume = {48},
    Year = {1998}}
@book{welsington1999,
    Address = {Berlin/New York},
    Author = {William Welsington},
    Title = {An Introduction to Biblatex},
    Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    Series = {Latex Guides},
    Shortauthor = {Wel.},
    Shorttitle = {Intr.},
    Volume = {449},
    Year = {1999}}
\end{filecontents} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname} 

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:full}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibhypertarget{\thefield{entrykey}:\the\value{instcount}}{%
      \usedriver
        {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}%
         \ifciteidem
           {\renewbibmacro*{author}{\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}%
            \renewbibmacro*{editor}{\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}}
           {}%
        }
        {\thefield{entrytype}}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext\footcite[Cf.][P. 82]{welsington1997}
\blindtext\footcite[Cf.][P. 5]{welsington1998}
\blindtext\footcite[Cf.][P. 13]{welsington1999}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: It says here that I shouldn't but I have to say thanks!

Comment: @eklisiarh If you want, you can upvote my answer.

Comment: It's good you managed to answer it before people closed this as a duplicate of something that is not the same. :-)

Comment: @pst Yeah, got there just in time `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should have that, because "ebd." corresponds to "ibid./ibidem" which is only used for the same *work*. It is "idem" that can be used for the same author (although it's not so common anymore).

Biblatex can track both of these, and the traditional styles do so. See the "trad" examples in the `examples` directory that comes with Biblatex. Even when they do the "idem" thing, they don't do it on the first citation of the work. The answer from moewe shows you how to do that.

You might want Latin instead of German. See `74-style-verbose-trad1.tex` that tells you about how to change that.

Note that when you repeat references to these works the `historische-zeitschift` will do its thing anyway.

By the way, the "shorttitle" is meant to differentiate between the works. Use values like "LaTeX", "BibTeX" and "Biblatex" instead of "Intr.", "Intr." and "Intr."!

Comment: Well, in German in that case we use "ders."/"dies." etc. for idem, which is what my answer implements.